# Uncharged Gluon Representation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics

I'm currently learning for an exam and in an old exam the question was posed:

```
If Gluons were uncharged, under which representation would they transform?
```

The correct answer was the adjoint representation, because it is real for $SU(3)$. Am I missing something obvious or does this make no sense at all? The gluons **do** transform according to the adjoint representation of $SU(3)$. This is a real representation, but this this only means that there is no anti-gluon octet. The anti-particle to a gluon is found again in the octet. $$octet \rightarrow octet $$ and not $$octet \rightarrow \bar{octet} $$ Therefore, the gluons aren't directly their own anti-particles, (in some sense the complete octet is) and do carry charge although they transform according to a real representation. Does anyone have a better answer to the question above or does it make no sense at all?

Comment: IMO, the question makes no sense - being *uncharged* means not transforming at all, i.e. transforming in the trivial rep, but gauge bosons *always* transform in the adjoint, and only for abelian $\mathrm{U}(1)$-theories the adjoint is trivial.